# Swagger not responding when adding urls from another django app

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, swagger, swagger-ui

I have a simple Django app and want to include urls to project urls.
Project urls look like this:

```
from drf_spectacular.views import (
    SpectacularAPIView,
    SpectacularSwaggerView,
)
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('api/schema/', SpectacularAPIView.as_view(), name='api-schema'),
    path('api/docs/', SpectacularSwaggerView.as_view(url_name='api-schema'), name='api-docs'),
    path('api/user/', include('user.urls')),
    #path('api/', include('LinkTaskApp.urls')),
]
```

And LinkTaskApp urls look like this:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import AccountListView

urlpatterns = [
    path('account/', AccountListView.as_view(), name='account-list'),
]
```

As soon as I uncomment in the main urls:

```
 #path('api/', include('LinkTaskApp.urls')),
```

I get following error when I start Swagger:

```
Failed to load API definition.
Errors
Hide
 
Fetch error
Internal Server Error /api/schema/
```

In browser, it looks like this:

```
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/schema/
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referrer Policy: same-origin
```

Also attaching my settings.py:

```
import os
import environ
from pathlib import Path


env = environ.Env(
    # set casting, default value
    DEBUG=(bool, False)
)


# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
environ.Env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR.parent, '.env'))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'LinkTaskApp.User'


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'LinkTaskApp',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'drf_spectacular'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'LinkTask.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'LinkTask.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {

    'default': {

        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',

        'NAME': env('DB_NAME'),

        'USER': env('DB_USER'),

        'PASSWORD': env('DB_PASSWORD'),

        'HOST': env('DB_HOST'),

        'PORT': env('DB_PORT'),

    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = 'static/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema',
}

SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    'COMPONENT_SPLIT_REQUEST': True,
}
```

Any Ideal how to successfully include this url and get swagger to work?

Answer (score 1):

Because your app not connected to main project urls. To connect do the following:

inside your apps add below code into urls:

```
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('LinkTaskApps', views.viewname)

app_name = 'appname'

urlpatterns = [
    path('',include(router.urls)),
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. But the error remains. Exactly same as it was. I attached my settings file.

Comment: It helped thanks!! I also had to change  view to viewsts.ViewSerclass AccountListView(viewsets.ViewSet):

Comment: I still cant see urls registerred bu router in Sagger. Any idea?

Comment: I marked it as unanswered because it is not full solution Swagger works however, I cannot see any apis registered in rooter on swagger page.

Comment: localhost:8000/api/docs/   Navigate to this route only then it will appear